# Button selection in Android

Tags: android, android-button

I have to create button options where each button performs specific task. So how to do the  button selection. The code I tried is here.

```
            Button b1      
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
              if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
              {      //do something
                       }
                      if(v.getId()==R.id.button2)
              {      //do something
                          }
                       });
```

For single button function its working fine with this code.

```
           Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
              if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
              {      //do something
                       }
                      }});
```

Comment: Implement onClickListener in your activity and register it with every buttons. Then in onClick() check button's id using switch case and perform specific task according to it.

Answer (score 3):

For example you have more than 3 buttons means,

First of all you have implement `OnClickListener`

```
for ex. public class ImageViewer extends Activity implements OnClickListener{}

Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button02);
Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button03);
```

After that,

```
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
b3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now, your implement `onClick`

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button01:
        //perform your task 
        break;
        case R.id.button02:
        //perform your task 
        break;
        case R.id.button03:
        //perform your task 
        break;
        }
        }
```

**You have only a single button click function means,**

```
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //perform your task
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes, it will. for Ex. ImageButton I1=(ImageButton )findViewById(R.id.button01);-->I1.setOnClickListener(this);--> give the id in onclick method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this pattern

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
{      
  //do something
}
if(v.getId()==R.id.button2)
{      
  //do something
}
```

you have to make your class implement "OnClickListener" and implement the "Onclick" method.
Then to set the listener to your buttons, you'll only have to set:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: A more graceful way to test the id would be to use the switch/case pattern... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // Listening to Login Screen link
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // do your stuff here
        }
    });
```

If you've multiple buttons, then, try this -

```
public class buttonsexample extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();
        if(id == R.id.button1)
        {
            // do your stuff here
        }else if(id == R.id.button2)
        {
            // do your stuff here
        }else if(id == R.id.button3)
        {
            // do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The magic of development is that you can always do what you want with many ways, hawaii.five-0... Some are just more graceful than others... ;)

Comment: you shouldn't choose many ways but only the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
                      }});

Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
        b2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
                      }});
```

and so on...

or alternatively

```
public class ABCActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            break;

    }
```

Comment: Isn't this a very long method? No direct switch case condition can be applied?]

Comment: Updated the answer and if you want to use `ImageButton` change it with `Button` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to implement OnClickListener you can do it like this

```
Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
b1.setOnClickListener(listen);
b2.setOnClickListener(listen);

OnClickListener listen=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch (v.getId()) {

             case R.id.button1:
             //perform your task 
             break;
             case R.id.button2:
             //perform your task 
             break;
             }

        }
    };
```

Comment: Use Switch case instead of using if